# Spring configurable bean injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Is there any way to inject bean dependencies make configurable except from factory pattern?
I have 3 class implement same interface and have 3 bean definition. I want to change that beans using in other class? For excample is it possile to read bean name form conf file and use it as varible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can go with `@Qualifier` annotation. As you have 3 classes which implement same interface, name those classes with different names and use `@Qualifier` annotation.

[Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) says : `autowiring by type may lead to multiple candidates, it is often necessary to have more control over the selection process. One way to accomplish this is with Spring's @Qualifier annotation.`

Comment: Thank you Nandkumar. I understand Qualifier but it is configured in class. I want to configure from property file. I think only way using factory pattern.